# Templated function specialization: linker error

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, linker, specialization

I am trying to specialize a function of two template arguments, when template argument types are same. I do it the following way:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>

using namespace std;

template<typename U, typename T>
int fun( U& u, T t );

template<>
inline
int fun( int& u, float t )
{
    cout << "int, float" << endl;
    return 0;
}

template<typename U, typename T>
inline
int fun( U& u, typename std::enable_if<std::is_same<U, T>::value ,T>::type t )
{
    cout << "U == T" << endl;
    return 0;
}

int main()
{
    int a;
    float b1, b2;

    fun(a, b1);
    fun(b1, b2);

    return 0;
}
```

This code compiles fine (GCC 4.8.2) but linker gives undefined refernces to all the `fun` calls when `U` and `T` are same type. Why doesn't it work?

---

**Linker output**:

```
g++ -std=c++11 test.cpp
```

```
/tmp/cc7HWboz.o: In function `main':
test.cpp:(.text+0x66): undefined reference to `int fun<float, float>(float&, float)'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Comment: Are there no linker errors when `T` and `U` are different?

Comment: @KerrekSB correct, see edited post for concrete example

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**THE PROBLEM**

Your `fun` that is using `std::enable_if` to protect instatiation from two types that differs has a major problem; it cannot implicitly deduce type `T`.

This means that when you are calling `fun` with `b1` and `b2` as parameters you are instantiating `template<typename U, typename T> int fun( U& u, T t )`, which hasn't got a definition.. hence the linker error.

---

**THE SOLUTION**

There are many alternatives to the code written below, but I reckon this might clear out some confusion.

```
template<
  typename U,
  typename T,
  typename = typename std::enable_if<std::is_same<U, T>::value>::type
>
inline int fun( U& u, T t)
{
    cout << "U == T" << endl;
    return 0;
}

inline int fun( int& u, float t )
{
    cout << "int, float" << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

In the above the compiler can deduce both `T` and `U` in our template, there is also no need for an *explicit specialization* of said template; we can make use of C++'s rules for overloading and have the compiler decide when `int&, float` is a better match than deducing `U&, T`.

Comment: Thanks. I tried `fun<float, float>(b1, b2)` and it works fine.